# regex replace string with tabs only

Tags: javascript, regex

How can use the RegEx to replace a string if ONLY it has a tab or sequence of tabs and ignore otherwise.

Example:

`str = "\t\t\t\t";` -> replace this string with nothing i.e. output of `str = "";`
`str = "\t";` -> replace this string with nothing i.e. output of `str = "";`

`str = "\t\tvar a = 10";` -> ignore replacing.

Thanks!

Comment: `str.replace(/^\t+$/, '')`?

Comment: awesome works... please post your answer so I can accept

Comment: There's already two perfectly valid answers that were posted after my comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex replace, it should be like this:

```
str.replace(/^\t+$/, '');
```

Comment: That matches only the strings that begins and ens with tabs!

Comment: @chsdk and that's expected.

Comment: @chsdk: that begins, ends and contains just tabs. Exactly as user3658423 needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should work.

```
str.replace(/^\t+$/, "");
```